# iPad "3" HTML5 Canvas Drawing Resolution

Tags: ipad, html, canvas

I've been toying around with iPad and HTML5 but since the display is retina, the text on my screen seems to be of low resolution. As do lines drawn with lineTo/moveTo/stroke. Note the text is drawn with context.fillText()

I suspect this is just because I haven't set up the canvas correctly to handle the retina pixel ratio, so hopefully someone here can figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong.

I have set up the canvas as follows:

```
<div id="container">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

With CSS attributes:

```
#canvas {
    width: 1024px; 
    height: 768px; 
}
#container {
    width: 1024px; 
    height: 768px; 
}
```

and in JavaScript (as I have seen to do on the internet) I have specified:

```
canvas.width = 2048;
canvas.height = 1536;
```

Unfortunately this does not stop the pixelation as it has for some other users.

Am I missing something or have I specified something incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your page head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

This tag makes sure that the page is shown in its original size, and remains in that size.